# Windows terminal: create .exe installer from .exe and .nsi

Tags: windows, terminal, nsis

I have a kivy project in python.

I build an `exe` with `Pyinstaller` based on this project.

I have a `.nsi` compiled which builds me an `.exe` installeur based on the previous `.exe`.

Everything works !

I am actually scripting the proccess to make it easier.

PROBLEM: What is the line of command that build an `.exe` installer based on a `.nsi` and an `.exe` ?

(To be really precise, I want to replace the "open HM NSIS Edit software, find your file.nsi, right click on it, click on 'Compile and Execute'" by a command line on a Windows terminal)

Comment: Are you asking which parameters are passed to MakeNSIS.exe?

Comment: Hum, I'm just manually opening "HM NSIS Edit" software and right clicking on my .nsi on "Compile and Execute". I want to do it with a line of command. I don't think I need paramaters ? I'm not sure if it's what you asked. :p

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the .nsi path to MakeNSIS:

```
"c:\Program Files\NSIS\MakeNSIS.exe "c:\mystuff\myinstaller.nsi"
```

It is possible to create extra defines with `/D` but you would know if your script requires this.

Comment: `pip3 install makensis` and `pip3 install nsis` don't work. :/ I can't do `makensis "c:\path\of\my_app.exe "c:\path\of\myinstaller.nsi"` (that's what I was suppose to try I suppose)

Comment: Just install NSIS normally from Sourceforge. Or use WinGet...

Comment: I already have "NSIS" and "HM NIS Edit" software but I still can't use line of command `makensis`. I feel dumb but I don't get what you are proposing :/

Comment: Use the full path to MakeNSIS.exe or make sure it is in %PATH%.